# Как вывести из MODx Revo Gallery последнюю картинку без указания номера альбома?

Tags: modx, изображения, gallery

Загвоздка в том что, требуется параметр - альбом.
А нужно вывести вообще последнюю загруженную картинку независимо от альбома.

Стандартный вывод первой картинки:

```
[[!Gallery?
             &album=`1`
             &thumbWidth=`200` 
             &thumbHeight=`200` 
             &thumbQuality=`50` 
             &activeCls=`gallery-active` 
             &itemCls=`gallery-item`
             &imageWidth=`1024`
             &imageHeight=`900`
             &limit=`1`
        ]]
```

Как переделать, чтобы получилось?

Comment: Создайте отдельный сниппет, который обратится к классу galItem и получит последнюю загруженную, зачем целую галерею дергать для такого. xPDO объекты очень просты в использовании, посмотрите в гугле куча документации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй для этого pdoTools:

```
[[!pdoResources? 
    &sortby=`id`
    &class=`galItem`
    &limit=`1`
    &sortdir=`DESC`
]]
```

не забудь указать свой чанк в &tpl для вывода